# Pouchdb work with cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, wkwebview, pouchdb

I have installed cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugin in my ionic v2 app. And also install pouchdb plugin. It was working fine. I have installed only pouchdb, not installed sqlite plugin not set any adapter.

I have tested in ios 10.2 - ipad

But ios 9 it was not working. Just show white screen.

this is my pouchdb code

```
    this._db = new PouchDB('test');
    this.remote = 'http://192.168.53.150:5984/test';

    let options = {
        live: true,
        retry: true
    };

    this._db.sync(this.remote, options);
```

> Ionic info

## cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.1
```

## global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

## local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

## System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
Node       : v6.11.0
npm        : 4.5.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

## PackageJson:

```
{
    "name": "listtest",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.50",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "pouchdb": "^6.3.4",
        "pouchdb-find": "^6.3.4",
        "rxjs": "5.4.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^2.1.3",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "ios"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You said `I have tested in ios 10.2 - ipad`.So is that working then?

Comment: Sampath now I modified my question. Please read it. For ios 9 what i will change in my code?

Comment: Which moment does it show `show a white screen.` on `Ios 9`?

Comment: After app launch

Comment: How do you know is that due to `pouchdb`? Did you disable it and test?

Comment: Ya I disable pouchdb initialize and test it. That time no problem. It was run normally.